# Creating boundaries on numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am looking for an algorithm that will help me create a boundary around the points on a 2-dim array that are not zero. Let me give an example.

I have the following array:]

[image]

I want an algorithm that will give me the most efficient way I can create a "barricade" around each of the little "islands". For context, each group of **1s** represent a source of resources in this resource management game, and I want to build walls around it to guard it from my opponent.

Essentially, this algorithm should give the value of the **2s** in the following figure:

[image]

There are a few points to this:

- The array is always square but the size of each dimension can vary from 12 to 40;
- Units cannot move on diagonals;
- There can be various islands (groups of **1s**), and can have all sorts of irregular shapes;
- Sometimes it might be more efficient to barricade two close by "islands" using the same barricade, if they are super close by.

Any ideas on this? I don't even know how to google this problem, so I ended up not finding anything. Thank you!

EDIT1: Code to create the initial array
EDIT2: Fixed the answer

```py
import numpy as np

size = 15
test_mat = np.zeros((size, size))
test_mat[(4, 5, 5, 6), (5, 4, 6, 5)] = 1
test_mat[(9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11), (8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 8, 10)] = 1
```

Comment: Can you please provide your example data as a copy-paste-able array?

Comment: Added in the EDIT.

Comment: Maybe look into the diffusion equation?

Comment: I would do a binary [dilation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation.html)/[erosion](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion.html)

Comment: Yep, I was fiddling with `ndimage.dilation` but wasn't really satisfied with any of my results. Not really familiar with `scipy.ndimage` though. Following this thread because I'm curious to see what others come up with.

Comment: I was playing around with applying convolutions, but the main problem for me is when there is a gap in the middle for example. There is got to be some optimisation algorithm for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import binary_dilation, binary_erosion

size = 15
test_mat = np.zeros((size, size))
test_mat[(4, 5, 5, 6), (5, 4, 6, 5)] = 1
test_mat[(9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11), (8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 8, 10)] = 1

dilated = binary_dilation(test_mat).astype(int)
eroded = binary_erosion(dilated)
borders = dilated-eroded
```

which gives:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Seems to be what I am looking for. I am not familiar with dilation and erosion, need to read on it and try a few other examples to see. Thank you! (Obv I will mark your answer if it fixes my issue). Thanks!!

Comment: `2 * borders + test_mat` gets you pretty close to what you want.

Comment: Yes these are definitely the operations that I need. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This does not solve my problem, just wanted to post an idea that I was playing with. Here goes the code:

```py
import numpy

# Generate the map
size = 15
test_mat = np.zeros((size, size))
test_mat[(4, 5, 5, 6), (5, 4, 6, 5)] = 1
test_mat[(9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11), (8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 8, 10)] = 1

# Find a solution by applying a convulsion
conv_mat = np.array([
        [0, 1, 0], 
        [1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0]])

conv = convolve(test_mat, conv_mat)
conv[test_mat > 0] = 0
conv[conv > 0] = 2
conv[test_mat > 0] = 1 # Mark the resources as 1
```

Using this code you get:

[image]

However, as you can see, when there is a gap, this does not find the right solution..